# D3.js appends null element when data is updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 selection like the one below where userData is a string array of user names:

```
var selector = container
   .selectAll(".userIcon").data(userData);
```

now I have a click command that adds data to the userData and appends circles for every user names.

```
userData.push(name);

selector = selector .data(userData).enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "userIcon");
```

But everytime I add a name in userData, I get nulls when I append the circle..

[image]

After adding third name:

[image]

After adding fourth name:

[image]

I don't know why I have nulls, when I append during enter. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the problem is here 'selector = selector .data(userData).enter()' it should be 'selector .data(userData).enter()' remove the equals

Comment: I can't believe I fail to notice that one... Thank you for giving light to my problem @Cyril... It is now OK..